# How to highlight the whole Stacked Bar

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

How to highlight the whole Stacked Bar when i click on any part of it. I'm use MPAndroidChart library

Example screen:[image: stackedbar]

Comment: redraw it with different color

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko i don't need different color, i need change part bar highlight to whole bar

Comment: what does `highlight` mean? **changing the color**? Then change the color (redraw with different color). You can redraw each part with different color as shown in the image

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko you work with mpandroid chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
chart.setHighlightFullBarEnabled(true);
```

work for me, but get bug
[image]